# Export a GeoJSON to GeoDataFrame using Folium, Leafmap or Ipyleaflet

Tags: python, geojson, mapping, folium, ipyleaflet

The title might be odd though, I'm currently working on a project using COLAB and trying to find a way to export a drawn polygon to a Geodataframe without downloading it to the local machine.

So the thing is that I can draw a polygon and export (download) it as GeoJSON using Folium *(via Draw plugin, export = True allows me to do that)*, then can assign it to a variable by linking the path like "./folder/polygon.geojson".

As I'm working on COLAB now, I'm still able to do it by uploading the downloaded GeoJSON back to the working environment (or Drive) and giving the path, etc. However, **I'm curious if there is a way to export a polygon drawn on Folium** (or Leafmap, ipyleaflet) **directly in the code, without having to download it.**

The worst case I'd be okay with would be exporting a drawn polygon directly to "/content" on COLAB.

**Update:** I found a way to save a polygon directly to "/content" on COLAB using Leafmap. It is very clear in the tutorials actually, it's just that the appearance of the library on COLAB is not really good (in terms of buttons, tools, label colors, etc.)